# Differences in ROC AUC values with cross_val_score and cross_val_predict

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, roc, auc

I am computing ROC AUC values for a Gradient Boosting Classifier using 10-fold cross validation with python sklearn. I have done this in two ways which I thought would give identical results, but they do not: (1) Use `cross_val_predict` with `method = 'predict_proba'` to get the predicted probabilities via cross validation, and then compute the AUC for each fold using `roc_auc_score`, versus (2) Use `cross_val_score` with `scoring = 'roc_auc'`. The results are not wildly different, but it bothers me that they differ at all (see code and output below). Can anyone explain this difference?

```
gbm = GradientBoostingClassifier(loss='deviance', n_estimators=initNumTrees, learning_rate=0.001, subsample=0.5, max_depth=1, random_state=12345, warm_start=True)

foldgen = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=12345)

cv_probs = cross_val_predict(gbm, X_train, y_train, method='predict_proba', cv=foldgen, n_jobs=n_cores)[:,1]
auc = []
for train_index, test_index in foldgen.split(X_train, y_train):
    auc.append(roc_auc_score(y_train[test_index], cv_probs[test_index]))

np.round(auc,4)
array([ 0.6713,  0.5878,  0.6315,  0.6538,  0.6709,  0.6724,  0.666 ,
    0.6857,  0.6426,  0.6581])
```

versus:

```
cv_values = cross_val_score(gbm, X_train, y_train, scoring='roc_auc', cv=foldgen, n_jobs=n_cores)

np.round(cv_values,4)
array([ 0.6391,  0.6159,  0.6673,  0.6613,  0.6748,  0.6754,  0.6869,
    0.7107,  0.6552,  0.6602])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same problem.

I read the documentation and found [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#defining-your-scoring-strategy-from-metric-functions) article. After that, I had started to use the method [make_scorer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer) instead of the literal string `roc_auc_score`.

So, that worked for me and now I can get the same result when I use the `cross_val_score` and the `StratifiedKFold`.

I hope being useful.